# How can find the voltages at 2 nodes with 1 equations and 2 variables?

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fArzkD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

At node 1, we have:$$0.001+i_1-i_4-i_5=0$$.
At node 2, we have: $$i_4+i_5+i_2=0$$.

$$i_1=\frac{0-V_1}{1000}=\frac{-V_x}{1000}$$(Vx is the voltage across R2)
$$i_2=\frac{0-V_2}{6000}$$
$$i_3=0.001A$$
$$i_4=i_1+i_3=-i_2-i_5$$
$$i_5=\frac{V_1-V_2}{1000}=\frac{V_x}{1000}$$

Use the equation at node 1, to find an expression for i4 and plug that into the equation at node 2: $$i_1+0.001+i_2=0$$
$$\frac{-V_x}{1000}+0.001-\frac{V_2}{6000}=0$$

**But there are V2 and Vx to solve in one equation.**

Comment: Your first equation(at node 1) should also include \$i_5\$ (going out of the node). Also, your expression for \$i_1\$ should be \$-\frac{V_x}{1000}\$ look at the polarity of \$V_x\$ with respect to \$i_1\$

Comment: It still not solvable. there is one equation at the end, but Vx and V2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have too much variables and arrows (not wrong, but unnecessary). I redrawed the circuit:

[image]

You obviously missed that the voltage over R4 can be expressed in terms of Vx. This is Kirchoffs voltage law.

I have written the current equations for nodes 1 and 2. There are 2 unknowns and 2 equations.

Hopefully clear now.